# Keyboard shortcut to quickly jump to the URL address field in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In Firefox I very often want to quickly enter a new URL in the address field. Therefore it would be very nice to be able to quickly jump to the URL address field with a keyboard shortcut! Today I must move my mouse and place the cursor in that field and also ensure that the current address is selected so I can overwrite it when entering the new URL. Very annoying!

I'm sure I'm not the first one to have this need so there is probably a shortcut or an extension that does this already, but I cannot find that information!

Answer (score 23):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

I prefer the first as it places both my hands ready to start typing.

Comment: `Alt + D` works on ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

Try **F6** on Windows (Where Ctrl+D is assigned otherwise).

[Full list of Firefox shortcuts](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts)

Comment: Whether F6 works for that depends on the "view state" of the browser (F6 toggles and there are also some ***weird view states*** Firefox can get into). A way to reset the state (e.g., for (blind) use with a macro keyboard) is `Ctrl` + `F` (for the find dialog) and `Esc`.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl-L works also

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> instead.

Comment: It was [never ever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X) "Mac OSX" or "OSX".