# Is there a keyboard shortcut to take your cursor into the URL bar for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcut to quickly jump to the URL address field in Firefox…](https://superuser.com/questions/83776/keyboard-shortcut-to-quickly-jump-to-the-url-address-field-in-firefox)

Is there a keyboard shortcut to take your cursor into the URL bar for Chrome?

I want to keep my fingers on the home-row. Is there a short cut that would take my cursor into the URL/Query input area, as opposed to having to click in it?

Comment: I'm not sure this should be flagged as an exact duplicate if asked about different browsers.  There is no set rule that browsers should have the same keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Windows:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

**Mac:**

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Check out more
in *[Keyboard and mouse shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=25799&answer=157179&rd=1)*.

Comment: +1, they work in pretty much every program that has an address bar.

Comment: CMD-L for mac works

Comment: This key has been roaming around to a new area between minor versions every 6 to 13 months for the last 15 years, so the only way to lock it down so it doesn't change is programming an applescripts under the hood to detect the key, detect the application, then forward your key to whatever keystroke it is for this cycle.

Comment: Notice that they don't work if you are in full screen mode (F11).

Answer (score 11):

F6 highlights the URL bar. I'm not sure if there is any shortcut for moving the actual cursor to the URL bar, though.

Comment: I suspect that that by ‘cursor’, the OA meant caret.

Comment: F6 jumps between Tab, URL Bar, Bookmarks Bar and Content, [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/257343/348985) is what I am looking for

Comment: Mac has removed the function rows so this is all marked for removal.  It's only a matter of time before Apple also removes the Fn, control, option and command keys, because all you need is the scrolling marquii up top with the options for 'watch tv', then 'buy it now'.  You'll have to get a 3rd party plugin and keyboard handset to regain access and control to the keyboard, and thus the computer.  Such as karabiner, shortkeys, and 3rd party hardware with a compatible $35 apple-dongle they make for 3 cents in china.