# Shortcut to focus on URL/"Awesome" Bar in Firefox?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcut to quickly jump to the URL address field in Firefox…](https://superuser.com/questions/83776/keyboard-shortcut-to-quickly-jump-to-the-url-address-field-in-firefox)

Is there a keyboard shortcut that can be used to focus the cursor to the URL/"Awesome" bar in Firefox 4? I'm just finding out how sweet it is and am really a proponent of not touching my mouse often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Control/Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Works in many other browsers as well (except IE, it brings up an "open" dialog).

Comment: That's sweet! Thanks a lot and even more helpful as I still use Chrome once in awhile... Never IE... Never... Unless I need to double check how poorly it rendered my website.

Comment: Heh, yeah. That's always something IE is good for.

Comment: Command-L on OS X.

Comment: Good point, @DanielBeck. Added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, works in many other browsers *and* IE.

Possibly doesn't work on all operating systems, though.  Checked and both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> do work for FF 16.0.1 in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Yep, Windows only. Doesn't work in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari on OS X.