# Keyboard shortcut to location bar without selecting all text

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, url

At [Keyboard shortcut to quickly jump to the URL address field in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/83776/keyboard-shortcut-to-quickly-jump-to-the-url-address-field-in-firefox) James Burton asked about the keyboard shortcut for jumping to the location bar.

This is very handy; however very often I don't want to type a whole new adress but add something to the url I'm on. Currently I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then have to press the right arrow.

Apparently this was the initial way of dealing with the keyboard-shortcut; but considered a bug (rightly so).

So, how could I define a keyboard shortcut to go to the address bar *without* selecting all text?

Comment: what happened to the answers that were written here?

Comment: May be the author deleted it himself because its possible that the answer was not helping. Or could be possible delete by a site moderator due to any wrong content.

Comment: there's only one answer here,no deleted posts or that sort

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut for this yet if I know correctly but you can do it by using `AutoHotKey` script very easily. First download the [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/download) for Windows and install it then run the following script.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx  

#IfWinActive, - Mozilla Firefox$

^m::Send ^l{End}
```

Here <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will focus to the address bar without selecting url.